# Add absence rows based on presence data

Tags: r

I have presence data  in R for individuals at 4 different sites on different days. I would like to create rows for every individual ID that was NOT seen at each site on each day, with an additional presence/absence column.

This is a subset of my presence data:

```
ID    SP SITE  DATE SMP
975    1    1 41579 FJB
997    1    1 41579 FAW
114    1    1 41579 FJW
926    2    1 41609 FJB
101    2    1 41609 FJB
108    2    1 41609 FAB
129    3    2 41710 FUB
131    3    2 41710 MAW
132    3    2 41710 FAW
```

This is what I would like to create:

```
ID    SP SITE  DATE SMP Present?
975    1    1 41579 FJB   Yes
997    1    1 41579 FAW   Yes
114    1    1 41579 FJW   Yes
926    1    1 41579 FJB   No
101    1    1 41579 FJB   No
108    1    1 41579 FAB   No
129    1    1 41579 FUB   No
131    1    1 41579 MAW   No
132    1    1 41579 FAW   No
975    2    1 41609 FJB   No
997    2    1 41609 FAW   No
114    2    1 41609 FJW   No
926    2    1 41609 FJB   Yes
101    2    1 41609 FJB   Yes
108    2    1 41609 FAB   Yes
129    2    1 41609 FUB   No
131    2    1 41609 MAW   No
132    2    1 41609 FAW   No
975    3    2 41710 FJB   No
997    3    2 41710 FAW   No
114    3    2 41710 FJW   No
926    3    2 41710 FJB   No
101    3    2 41710 FJB   No
108    3    2 41710 FAB   No
129    3    2 41710 FUB   Yes
131    3    2 41710 MAW   Yes
132    3    2 41710 FAW   Yes
```

I hope someone may be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to prepare a data set that contains all possible combinations of ID, SP, SITE, DATE and SMP and I call it `attendance_list`.

```
library(tidyverse)
txt <- "ID    SP SITE  DATE SMP
975    1    1 41579 FJB
997    1    1 41579 FAW
114    1    1 41579 FJW
926    2    1 41609 FJB
101    2    1 41609 FJB
108    2    1 41609 FAB
129    3    2 41710 FUB
131    3    2 41710 MAW
132    3    2 41710 FAW"
presence_data <- txt %>% 
  gsub(" +", " ", x=.) %>% 
  read.delim(text=., sep=" ")

# Attendance list
## It looks like each ID has only one SMP
id_smp <- presence_data %>% 
  select(ID, SMP) %>% 
  distinct()
## Working site and date
sp_site_date <- presence_data %>% 
  select(SP, SITE, DATE) %>% 
  distinct()
attendance_list <- merge(id_smp, sp_site_date)
```

Then, you can left join the `presence_data` with a 'Yes' column to `attendance_list`, and replace 'NA' (Data in `attendance_list` but not in `presence data`) by 'No'.

```
attendance_list <- attendance_list %>% 
  left_join(presence_data %>% mutate(PRESENT="Yes"), by=c("ID", "SMP", "SP", "SITE", "DATE")) %>% 
  mutate(PRESENT = ifelse(is.na(PRESENT), "No", PRESENT))
```

---

**Output:**

```
> attendance_list
#     ID SMP SP SITE  DATE PRESENT
# 1  975 FJB  1    1 41579     Yes
# 2  997 FAW  1    1 41579     Yes
# 3  114 FJW  1    1 41579     Yes
# 4  926 FJB  1    1 41579      No
# 5  101 FJB  1    1 41579      No
# 6  108 FAB  1    1 41579      No
# 7  129 FUB  1    1 41579      No
# 8  131 MAW  1    1 41579      No
# 9  132 FAW  1    1 41579      No
# 10 975 FJB  2    1 41609      No
# 11 997 FAW  2    1 41609      No
# 12 114 FJW  2    1 41609      No
# 13 926 FJB  2    1 41609     Yes
# 14 101 FJB  2    1 41609     Yes
# 15 108 FAB  2    1 41609     Yes
# 16 129 FUB  2    1 41609      No
# 17 131 MAW  2    1 41609      No
# 18 132 FAW  2    1 41609      No
# 19 975 FJB  3    2 41710      No
# 20 997 FAW  3    2 41710      No
# 21 114 FJW  3    2 41710      No
# 22 926 FJB  3    2 41710      No
# 23 101 FJB  3    2 41710      No
# 24 108 FAB  3    2 41710      No
# 25 129 FUB  3    2 41710     Yes
# 26 131 MAW  3    2 41710     Yes
# 27 132 FAW  3    2 41710     Yes
```